# Is there a way to make the Liningen REPL show a log of the vim+fireplace interactions?

Tags: vim, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I have been working with Clojure, VIM, fireplace, and Leiningen REPL and I'm starting to get somewhat productive with it.

However, I was wondering if there is a way for the results of evaluation (from VIM, ccp for example) to show up in the Leiningen REPL console as well instead of just in the output section of the of VIM screen (bottom).  I'd like to see a log of all of the interactions with the REPL.

I also use VisualStudio and F# and I was looking for something similar to the F# Output Window concept.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [vim-slime plugin](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime).

I hope this [blog post](http://michaelalynmiller.com/blog/2013/02/27/vim-tmux-clojure/) can help.